# Mapping tables from another tablespace with doctrine e oracle

Tags: oracle, laravel, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Laravel with doctrine and oracle. All good until now.

Let's imagine a structure in oracle like this:

Tablespace daily:

- orders
- orders_itens

Tablespace neg: (tablespace of the negotiation system)

- users

The login on negotiation is in the neg.users table, but the orders are saved in daily.orders.

I connect with the user 'neg', so the doctrine only found the users table.

How can I map the daily.orders and daily.orders_itens table?

Comment: Configure two entity managers, one for each database. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: Oops.  I gave you a link to Symfony.  I'm sure Laravel has the same capability.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Tks for your help! I'll to create 2 providers and call then on the config/app.php and try this tip. I'm stil confuse because to reference the table i believe that need add the tablespace like 'neg.users'

As soon as possible i'll return here to tell you the result!

One more time, tks!

Comment: You would only need neg.users if you want to join across the table spaces.  I would suggest that you avoid doing that.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do that... It's how our DB was projected... =/

I still can not do the providers.. I'm still trying...